# Не могу получит доступ к django сайту на gogole cloud сервере

Tags: python, django, сервер, backend

всем привет. У меня сервер на google cloud типа N1 в зоне uscentral1a. Намигрировал джанго проект, Установил все нужное на сервере, сконфигурировал settings.py(AllowedHosts, StaticRoot) и запустил runserver на 0.0.0.0:8000, попитлася получит резултат через броузер, но загрузка длится вечно. попробовал allow=TCP:8000 allow=UDP:8000 allow=HTTP:8000 но без разници. ест идеи?